# Do I need to install Ruby before installing Ruby on Rails from official sources for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed Ruby 2.4.4 Development Kit. Then I installed Ruby on Rails Installer for Windows.

```
ruby -v
```

gave me before Rails installation the correct version 2.4.4 but now I only have 2.3.3

I tried to reinstall Ruby 2.4.4 but it never changed the version back to 2.4.4.

Did I make a mistake by installing Ruby and should I just deinstall everything again and install Ruby on Rails if it comes with Ruby anyways?

OR am I completely wrong and everything is just fine as it is? Do I now have multiple redundant versions of Ruby or is it intended?!

Pls help my confusion

Thnak you

Comment: Since you are on windows, it is easy for you. Go to http://railsinstaller.org/en and install the exe. But before that remove everything ruby related. That rails installer will take care of your ruby setup.

Comment: but here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html under 3 it also states that a prerequisite is to have Ruby installed allready?!

Comment: That package has everything. Dont panic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do I need to install Ruby before installing Ruby on Rails from official sources for Windows***

The simple answer is ***Yes***.

If you install using **[RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)** then don't need this before because this software has included with Ruby.

**[RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)** packages included are

```
Ruby
Rails
Bundler
...
```

**The Simple Steps**

Follow those steps, actually, I have installed Ruby on Rails to many windows machine using these steps.

**Step 1:** Download [Git BASH](https://gitforwindows.org/) as the BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX environments.

**Step 1.1:** Download and install latest NodeJS from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and check the NodeJS version

```
$ node -v
#=> v6.11.5 # or something like this
```

**Step 2:** Download the ruby latest version [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and install it in your directory. Check the Ruby version

```
$ ruby -v
#=> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]
# or something like this
```

**Step 3:** Download Devkit [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) take the suitable one for matching your windows bit like 32 or 64 bit

**Step 4:** Create a devkit folder inside Ruby directory that means where created a default directory after installing ruby software, something like this `disk (:C) or (:D)/Ruby25/devkit/`

**Step 5:** Extract the DevKit file inside the `devkit` folder

**Step 6:** Open your GIT BASH inside the devkit folder and run this two commands

```
$ ruby dk.rb init
$ ruby dk.rb install
```

if above command running properly then done.

**Step 7:** Now you can run rails command for installing inside ruby folder

```
 $ gem install rails
```

**Step 8:** Check the Rails version

```
 $ rails -v
 #=> Rails 5.0.6
```

if till now all are steps is ok? that's it, now run rails command and create a rails project, like

```
$ rails new project
 create
    create  README.md
    create  Rakefile
    create  config.ru
    create  .gitignore
    create  Gemfile
    create  app
    create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
    ............
```

Hope it helps